# Send Email Extended action did not send email

Tags: workflow

I have created a SharePoint workflow in SP Designer 2010 for a automated email sending functionality when a list item is modified.

1. I am able to send email with `Send an Email` action. But when I use `Send Email Extended`, I am not getting the email. I can add users in the `Define Email Message` dialogue box. But later if I open the action's property box, I'm seeing the `RecipientTO` and `RecipientCC` fields are showing `"No Builder Specified"`. How can I input TO and CC address fields?
2. If I want to add a BCC field how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To add a BCC field

1. Since you are in SP Designer, first create an "SEND EMAIL" action.
2. Once its configured, select the above action & click on ADVANCED PROPERTIES from RIBBON
3. There you will have a BCC field, fill it up